# Conditional type based on field of the same type

Tags: typescript

I have a function that generates an array of objects called nodes:

```
type Node = {
  type: 'text' | 'entity';
  // A node of type 'entity' for sure has props defined while a 'text' node does not have them.
  // I also require those nodes to be in the same array when returned from the buildNodes function
  props?: EntitySpecificProps;
}

type EntitySpecificProps = {
  id: string;
}


function buildNodes(): Node[] {
 ...
 return nodes;
}
```

Now let's say I generate some nodes and pass them to another function which is defined as:

```
function useEntityNode(props: EntitySpecificProps){
   ...
}

const nodes = buildNodes();
// typescript gives error because node props may be possibly undefined (given the optional type of 'props').
nodes.map((node) => node.type === 'text' ? node : useEntityNode(node.props))
```

How can I constrain node props to be defined if the type field of a node is of type `entity`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make this work by removing the `Optional "?"` from props when type is `"entity"` by using this `NodeUnion` mapping transformation.

`NodeUnion` makes sure that if `type = "text"` we get `{ type: "text", props ?: T }`

If `type = "entity"` we get `{ type: "entity", props: T }` ie Props field becomes required

```
export type Node = {
  type: 'text' | 'entity';
  props?: EntitySpecificProps;
}

/*  This makes sure that if type = 'text' we get { type: 'text', props ?: T }
 if type = 'entity' we get { type: 'entity', props: T } ie Props field becomes required
 */

export type NodeUnion = 
  | Node["type"] extends infer T 
    ? T extends any  
      ? T extends 'entity' 
        ? Required<Node> & { type: T }
        : Node & { type: T }
      : never 
    : never

export type EntitySpecificProps = {
  id: string;
}

declare function buildNodes(): NodeUnion[] 

declare function useEntityNode(props: EntitySpecificProps): void

const nodes = buildNodes();

nodes.map((node) => node.type === 'text' ? node : useEntityNode(node.props))
```

[Code Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcByEAmqC8cDeAsAFBwLLABccA5DKDDXAD63AB2MAlkjQNwkyYKBDABnAPzUAopx6IAyigDGXAGZdlABRHiBxAL4kSAegBUZACoALLmLgBbAIYBrYPbEBXKKhjWn8OrkKHB4dAxMAO6oAObA8PjBVLT0IIwANHDCovZScJZwRqRBSCFhHNy8cNFwcQlJ1DQV8jSZ2eLUBQZwXKg6OXAawAA2mHAARsDKEA7ucD4Ajp5cPpiCZibGxKCQsEnoWMAAquxcEOyhcIIsB9gA2gBEpcAPALpwDByY9lzsasBQfJXUhkOASIGfdjfOBOdiIMjXUFgiFpL72JpyKqIpHIgBKwCWK2AmAAPBhsAA%20OAAMgIDSBRRxoOo5NQtMSz06hWxZGo7GAADcAcCkXzBQCtjtoPBnnBZJVFCp1Jp%20uJLkQQVxMNQxDAoL8YvoiiRsMphk4fINPOxlNxzhNlqNWWIABQAShZhxOZ3Yd3eW1N5stamttp9cE8YmA8vkrJd7TEMkxiqmyu0ujEHrgAogWq203Yurg7EO9jw40dmGd7v0JBL2DEADpnGAXS768A3aEqR3G7KcAOUhFkR24NRI9Hk3Hewm3W6gA)

Comment: This definitely works, but I'd love to understand how that works

Comment: Sure, I'll write up step by step explanation for this by tonight

Comment: @MarcoRipamonti As promised, here is the in-depth explanation behind this wizardry :)

[Explantion](https://twitter.com/jha_bisu/status/1519676672915939329?s=20&t=uygc4O7refkIW-_LcMT5qQ)

Comment: Thank you very very much! The only thing that isn't clear to me is the `T extends any` part. Why can't I just do what comes after it?

Comment: Basically what we want is that union to distribute,  if T will be A | B and we want T to have one value at time like T = A once and then T = B we make use of `distributive` property of Conditional types. It basically means we just need to have any statement that yields true... Ex `T extends any` `T extends T` all of these do the same thing

Answer (score 0):

You could specify all possible `Node` sub-types in their separate `type`. The types can then be discriminated by their `type` property.

```
type _Text = {
  type: 'text'
}

type Entity = {
  type: 'entity'
  props: EntitySpecificProps
}

type EntitySpecificProps = {
  id: string;
}

type _Nodes = _Text | Entity

function buildNodes(): _Nodes[] {
 return [];
}

function useEntityNode(props: EntitySpecificProps){}

const nodes = buildNodes();
nodes.map((node) => node.type === 'text' ? node : useEntityNode(node.props))
```

Note: I prefixed some types here with an `_` because the names `Text` and `Node` collide with existing types.

Comment: We can create discriminated unions based on the "type" property dynamically using a type alias like this - [Code Playground](https://tsplay.dev/mq52jm)